# place 2 divs inside 1 and return as innerHtml

Tags: javascript, html, innerhtml

I can return a table as div in innerHTML but would like to add a header above the div. So have created 3 divs. 1 div for the header, 1 div for the table, then place the 2 divs inside a third.
This is not working:

Comment: HTML tags like `<b>`, `<center>` and `<font>` have been deprecated. You should use CSS instead. Also, `</br>` is not a valid HTML element — I think you mean `<br />`?

Comment: `document.createElement('divTable')` should be `document.createElement('div')`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have several mistakes.

First of all the elements you should create are `div` not `divTable`. It should be:

```
var div1 = document.createElement('div');
div1.appendChild(table);
```

Then you can't append `featureTag` because it's a string, so use `innerHTML` in this case:

```
var featureTag = "<center><b> <FONT COLOR='FF6600'> Feature Properties </FONT> </b> </center> </br>";

var div2 = document.createElement('div');
div2.innerHTML = featureTag;
```

Something like this: http://jsfiddle.net/epuf5fgd/

Comment: Because it's a property, not a function. Should be `div2.innerHTML = featureTag;`.